# FileUpload and UpdatePanel: ScriptManager.RegisterPostBackControl works the second time

Tags: c#, asp.net-ajax, file-upload, updatepanel

I'm developing an ASP.NET application with C# and Visual Studio 2008 SP1. I'm using WebForms.

I have an ASPX page with two UpdatePanels, one on the left that holds a TreeView and other on the right where I load dynamically user controls.

One user control, that I used on right panel, has a FileUpload control and a button to save that file on server. The ascx code to save control is:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelBotons" runat="server" RenderMode="Inline" 
    UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="Save" runat="server" Text="Guardar" 
                onclick="Save_Click" CssClass="button" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Save" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I make a full postback to upload the file to the server and save it to database. But I always getting False on FileUpload.HasFile.

I problem is the right UpdatePanel. I need it to load dynamically the user controls. This panel has three UpdatePanels to load the three user controls that I use.

Maybe I can use an Async File Uploader or delete the right Update Panel and do a full postback to load controls dynamically.

Any advice?
**UPDATE:**

`RegisterPostBackControl` **works**... the second time I click on save button. First time FileUpload.HasFile is FALSE, and second time is TRUE.

**Second Update**
On first click I also check ScriptManager.IsInAsyncPostBack and is FALSE. I don't understand ANYTHING!!

Why?

The code to load user control first time, and on each postback is:

```
DynamicControls.CreateDestination ud =
            this.LoadControl(ucUrl) as DynamicControls.CreateDestination;
if (ud != null)
{
    Button save = ud.FindControl("Save") as Button;
    if (save != null) 
        ScriptManager1.RegisterPostBackControl(save);
    PanelDestination.Controls.Add(ud);
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

For me this solution worked:

add
Page.Form.Attributes.Add("enctype", "multipart/form-data");

The enctype attribute is missing on the first postback.

http://adamnoffie.blogspot.com/2007/10/file-upload-not-working-on-first.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution.

Answer (score 3):

Put the following in your form tag:

enctype="multipart/form-data"

Answer (score 1):

Fill Upload requires a full post, and if you use a Update Panel, it does a partial post back. So, FileUpload by itself will not work. You will have to handle it differently by calling the `RegisterPostBackControl`.

See this link for details --> [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20100706212558/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/mmintoff/archive/2009/04/01/fileupload-within-updatepanel.aspx)

Comment: Ok. How can I register a button inside my user control from the page. I'm seeing that I only can register the hole control. Imagine that the user control is myUserControl, and the button is Save. Can I do something like ScriptManager1.RegisterPostBackControl(myUserControl.Save); I don' want to do a full postback each time the user click on a button from that user control.

Comment: I've updated my question. I'm doing a full postback but FileUpload doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

In response to your second update,

I had this exact problem, and I believe it has to do with the fact that you are adding a dynamic control to your page inside of the UpdatePanel.

There may be a better way to do it out there, as I am certainly no ASP.NET expert, but I was able to solve this problem on my own by adding the control in a div that was hidden using CSS -before- it was needed, and then auto-incrementing the "dummy" control's ID so there are no conflicts, and I can keep adding as many as I want.  That way, when the UpdatePanel is triggered it fully recognizes the controls and their contents, excepting the hidden ones of course.

I am using XSL to transform my XML into a dynamic page that includes ASP.NET controls, so essentially I did the following:

```
<div class="hide">
    <asp:FileUpload CssClass="upload" identity="addVersion_{@id}_{count(draft) + 1}" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button Text="Add File" identity="addVersionBtn_{@id}_{count(draft) + 1}" fileControlIdentity="addVersion_{@id}_{count(draft) + 1}" action="addVersion" runat="server" />
</div>
```

---

And then in the code-behind:

```
Protected Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
    //Code to generate the data (stripped out because it is generated in a different manner than the original poster)

    //Add events for all of the new-found controls depending on their type
    recursiveAddEvents(nameOfPlaceHolder.Controls)
End Sub


//Add events for all of the new-found controls depending on their type
Sub recursiveAddEvents(ByRef controls As ControlCollection)
    For Each con As Control In controls
        If con.Controls.Count > 0 Then
            recursiveAddEvents(con.Controls)
        End If

        //Try to cast the control to different data types
        Dim btn As Button = TryCast(con, Button)
        Dim file As FileUpload = TryCast(con, FileUpload)

        //Test to see which type the control was and apply the actions to it
        If Not btn Is Nothing Then
            //Assign the correct click events
            If btn.Attributes.Item("action") = "addVersion" Then
                AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf addDraftVersion
                btn.ID = btn.Attributes.Item("identity")

                //Register the control with the ScriptManager
                ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterPostBackControl(btn)
            End If
        ElseIf Not file Is Nothing Then
            //Assign the correct click events
            file.ID = file.Attributes.Item("identity")
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Protected Sub addDraftVersion(ByVal sender As Button, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim fileName as String = sender.Attributes("title").Replace(" ", "_") & "_D" & info("draftID") & "_V" & info("versionID")
    Dim inputControl As FileUpload = TryCast(trackPH.FindControl(sender.Attributes("fileControlIdentity")), FileUpload)

    If inputControl Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    //Do whatever need to be done

    //Trigger UpdatePanel(s)
    nameOfUpdatePanel.Update()
End Sub
```

---

I stripped out a lot of the code, but it should still get the general idea across :)

Answer (score 1):

I had to combine both advices here. I am using an UpdatePanel to dynamically load an UserControl and the FileUpload is in the UserControl. I had to:

- RegisterPostBackControl in the user control's Page_Load
- add enctype="multipart/form-data" to the form element of the page, which contains the update panel, the code Page.Form.Attributes.Add("enctype", "multipart/form-data"); didn't work for me, it had to be in the aspx

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me, only when I put it in the Page_Init

```
Private Sub Page_Init(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
    Page.Form.Attributes.Add("enctype", "multipart/form-data")
End Sub
```