# FileUpload not working in Multiview and updatepanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, multiview

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
<Triggers>
<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" />
</Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>

<asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server" 
                 ActiveViewIndex="0">           
    <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server">
        <asp:Button Text="next"
            runat="server" onclick="Unnamed1_Click" />
    </asp:View>
    <asp:View ID="View2" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" 
        style="width: 56px" />
    <asp:FileUpload ID="fileupload2" runat="server" />
    </asp:View>
</asp:MultiView>
 </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and the code behind is

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (fileupload2.HasFile)
        {
            //code..
        }
    }
    protected void Unnamed1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 1;
    }
```

When i click Button1 for uploading the image on  first time the fileupload2.HasFile returns "false"

without refrshing the page again try to upload the same picture then    fileupload2.HasFile returns "true"

**Working Properly in View1. Problem is with View 2**

What is the problem with that fileupload ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try registering the button control with [RegisterPostBackControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerpostbackcontrol.aspx) early in the page lifecycle:

```
   protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       ScriptManager1.RegisterPostBackControl(Button1);
   }
```

See Also:

[FileUpload and UpdatePanel: ScriptManager.RegisterPostBackControl works the second time.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264541/fileupload-and-updatepanel-scriptmanager-registerpostbackcontrol-works-the-secon)

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why but when I add a fake upload file out of the multiview, the file upload works correctly inside view2.

I hope this can still help someone

**Code example that should work, but does not work as expected**

[image]

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>  
        <asp:MultiView ActiveViewIndex="0" runat="server" ID="mv">
            <asp:View runat="server" ID="view1">
                <asp:Button ID="change" Text="Change View" runat="server" OnClick="change_Click" />
            </asp:View>

            <asp:View runat="server" ID="view2"> 
                <div id="divLogo" runat="server" class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Image</label>
                    <ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload ID="fileUploadImage" runat="server"
                        AllowMultiple="false" CssClass="fileUpload" PersistFile="true" />
                </div>
                <asp:Button ID="save" Text="Save" runat="server" OnClick="save_Click" />
            </asp:View>
        </asp:MultiView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Example of code that works as expected with an auxiliary fake fileupload**

[image]

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div style="display: none;">
            <ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload ID="AsyncFileUploadFake" runat="server"
                AllowMultiple="false" CssClass="fileUpload" PersistFile="true" />
        </div>
        <asp:MultiView ActiveViewIndex="0" runat="server" ID="mv">
            <asp:View runat="server" ID="view1">
                <asp:Button ID="change" Text="Change View" runat="server" OnClick="change_Click" />
            </asp:View>

            <asp:View runat="server" ID="view2"> 
                <div id="divLogo" runat="server" class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Image</label>
                    <ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload ID="fileUploadImage" runat="server"
                        AllowMultiple="false" CssClass="fileUpload" PersistFile="true" />
                </div>
                <asp:Button ID="save" Text="Save" runat="server" OnClick="save_Click" />
            </asp:View>
        </asp:MultiView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that the UpdatePanel "converts" all requests from controls inside it to AJAX requests, and FileUpload doesn't work with AJAX. If you [Google for "fileupload updatepanel"](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&sugexp=ldymls&xhr=t&q=fileupload+updatepanel&cp=12&qe=ZmlsZXVwbG9hZCB1&qesig=jhWJazoBUOf0tmTfqs0Xkw&pkc=AFgZ2tmPnggyx0Ky8QFT4PFXw8bwBkzihoJh0MKDhtZVBVSX5I1hvFuPtljBXXPlrkHFN7zkFYukkvPnJzeU94Opw7pvCA1vSA&pf=p&sclient=psy&aq=0&aqi=&aql=&oq=fileupload+u&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.&fp=369c8973645261b8), you'll see a bunch of articles and possible workarounds.

The reason why it's not working in View2 is that the button with id "Button1" has a trigger defined in the triggers section of the UpdatePanel. Defining such a trigger for a button will "ajaxify" it, so pushing the button will send an AJAX request instead of a "normal" postback.

Comment: i found lot of articles.. but didnt found nay workarounds.. its working properly in view1... but the problem is with view2

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the AsyncFileUpload control from AjaxControlToolkit?

http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/AsyncFileUpload/AsyncFileUpload.aspx

Classic FileUpload does not really work well with AJAX and UpdatePanels.

Answer (score 0):

Obtained from http://forums.asp.net/p/1105208/1689084.aspx

> To use a FileUpload control inside an
>   UpdatePanel control, set the postback
>   control that submits the file to be a
>   PostBackTrigger control for the panel.

Alternatively, you could use an iframe. The specific code isn't with me right now, but if you want it, I can dig it out when I have a chance to open my old drive.

As for the problem when the file is no longer available in view 2, you could probably try to save the file in View 1 and then retrieve it later in View 2. The reason is probably because the file is submitted once in view 1 and never resubmitted in view 2.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have to set triggers Postback for every event around the fileupload. Even, the button which raise the view where the fileupload is.

So, try this. It should work.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
<Triggers>
<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" />
</Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>

<asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server" 
                 ActiveViewIndex="0">           
    <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server">
        <asp:Button Text="next" id="btnNext"
            runat="server" onclick="Unnamed1_Click" />
    </asp:View>
    <asp:View ID="View2" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" 
        style="width: 56px" />
    <asp:FileUpload ID="fileupload2" runat="server" />
    </asp:View>
</asp:MultiView>
 </ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnNext" />
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```